# Defining a group of cell names using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a question,  I am trying to define a cell name in excel using vba. Now to select one cell only i have been using the following code which proves to work fine: 
`Range("A1").Name = "zm_1"`

However I need to name a number of cells in a column i.e:

`Range("A1").Name = "zm_1"
Range("A2").Name = "zm_2"
Range("A3").Name = "zm_3"
Range("A4").Name = "zm_4"`

Since this is quite tedious for 100 cells, i have been trying to use an array:

`For i=1 to 100
Range("A(i)").Name = "zm_(i)"
next`

^ this however gives an error which i have been unable to track. Any ideas/suggestions on how can it be done? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with `Range("A(i)").Name = "zm_(i)"` The " indicate that something is text, so you should place your (i) out of the ".

For the first part it is quiet easy, as you can also use the row and column way of describing the cell. Therefore that becomes

`Range(Cells(i,1)).Name`

For the second part you need to concatenate the text and the numbers. That becomes: `"zm_" & i`

Comment: You're welcome. Als have a look at the answer of Paresh J, explicitly referencing the workbook and worksheet is a good thing to keep in mind. If your code is small and only consist of one workbook and worksheet this way would behave no different then his, however when more worksheets or workbooks come into play it is definetly important to reference to the correct ones. Your code now just assumes that the workbook that is open is the one calculations should be performed on, but when multiple sheets come into play it is essential to explicitly tell the code were to go.

Comment: @user5702568, could you also acknowledge my answer by accepting it, and by doing so also let others know this question is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an array, just your loop:

```
For i = 1 to 100
Range("A" & i).Name = "zm_" & i
next
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code and hope it helps you:

```
For i = 1 To 100
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A" & i).Name = "zm_" & i
Next
```

Where `Sheet(1)` refers to Sheet1 of the current workbook.